# madExcept.obj not found when building in Team CIty

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, c++builder, madexcept

I build a *C++ Builder 2010* project using *Team City* and noticed that I got issues when adding *madExcept*. The build complains about not finding *MADEXCEPT.OBJ*. My guess is that the *standard* include paths added in the *C++ Builder 2010 IDE* aren't propagated to the *Team City* build. Since the *.cbproj* files conatins no reference to where to locate *madExcept* the build fails. Am I right and how do I best rectify this? Building in the *IDE* on the *Build Agent* works fine and even using the *RAD Studio Command Prompt*, just when *Team City* is doing the build it fails. The thing that makes it extra strange is that there is no variable set when using *RAD Studio Command Prompt* that points to *madExcept* either, but it still works.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but did you add an extra build step for madExceptPatch.exe? Otherwise, madExcept probably won't work, see http://help.madshi.net/madExceptFaq.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that *madExcept* and the entire *mad suite* adds references to the include files and libraries to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\...
```

Since the *TeamCity* build agent runs as another user this information is not available to it.